# Applying script to a single column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use the following generic script, and only apply it to a specific column. How would I specify this to say, column F within the sheet?

```
function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
   var range = e.range;

 // if you want to test a specific sheet, un-comment the following the following and move the range test inside this if   
/* if (range.getSheet().getName() === 'required sheet') {
    // do something
}*/

   if (range.getColumn() == 6) {// 6 is for col F

    range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());

   }
}
```

This should work. It tests the column of the range if it is F (6 in this case) and sets the note.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Karan's great answer. With this you can modify a row and update a column within the modified row.

```
function onEdit(e) {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
   var row = e.range.getRow(); 

   // 'A' specifies the columns

   var range = sheet.getRange('A'+ row)
   Logger.log(range)
   range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());

}
```